# Porqué no se aplican los estilos css a todas clas clases

Tags: selectores-css

Necesito ayuda con una problema sencillo pero que no he podido resolver. Basicamente tengo tres `div` y los tres tienen una clase compartida; al usar `queryselector` me cambia la clase del primer `div` pero al usar `queryselectorAll` o `getelementbyclassname` me dice

> htmlstruct.js:160 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'opacity' of
> undefined...

De antemano gracias!!!

Comment: ¿Has intentado usar Jquery en lugar de l DOM? Además, es getElementsByClassName (en plural).  Un saludo,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"querySelectorAll" y "getElementByClassName" devuelven una lista de todos los elementos que cumplen el requisito, no un elemento en especial.

Si quieres colocar estilos especiales a todo ellos tendrías que hacer un bucle para colocárselos a todos.

```
var elemento = docuement.querySelector('elemento')

for (var i = 0 ; i < elemento.length; i++) {
   elemento[i].addEventListener('click' , tuFuncion , false ) ; 
}
```

O si quieres colocárselo a uno en concreto seria:

```
var elemento = docuement.querySelector('elemento')
var num = 0 // Numero del objeto de la lista a modificar

elemento[num].addEventListener('click' , tuFuncion , false ) ;
```

No solo puede ser un addEventListener, está permitido todo tipo de interacción y cualquier cosa loca que se te ocurra...

espero haberte solucionado tu problema. ¡feliz haking!

Comment: Si me funcionó gracias @CarlosPonce  !!!!